# "if else" to read characters and make some optional output

Tags: android, shell, if-statement

I need a shell script for android that can read some characters, for example `0,1,2,3,4,5` inside /system/boom.sh file and I want to create some option like

```
If 0,1,2,3,4,5 inside /system/boom.sh then bang in /system/log.sh  
If 0,1,2,3,4,6 inside /system/boom.sh then bing in /system/log.sh  
Else bung in /system/log.sh
```

The Script is for Android not for Linux

Comment: Which shell (can depend on the Android version)?

Comment: for every Android, any version, i just need the `if` statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely clear what you mean, I'm assuming there is just a single string n the file.  This should give you an idea of the syntax:

```
    infile='/system/boom.sh'
    outfile='/system/log.sh'

    read < "$infile"

    if [[ $REPLY == '0,1,2,3,4,5' ]]
    then
        bang > "$outfile"

    elif [[ $REPLY == '0,1,2,3,4,6' ]]
    then
        bing > "$outfile"
    else
        bung > "$outfile"
    fi
```

Comment: Thanks that is what i need, i know my english not so good so im sorry to